# Google App Engine Curl Not 24 Hours Run

Tags: google-app-engine, curl

I use Google App Engine with Curl Function. I have enabled my payment so it should work fine.

I create a PHP file in Google App Engine that contains curl function. I call it with cron job every minute. The cron job is running well every minute for 24 hours, but the curl function can't be executed for 24 hours. Here is the screenshot of my Google App Engine activities:

[image: My Google App Engine Summary Activities]

Everyday my curl function can't be executed from 1 AM to 1 PM, and run again normally from 1 PM to 1 AM.

I don't know what's wrong, I have checked my program and cron job setting and there is nothing wrong.

Is there something wrong in my Google App Engine setting?

Please help me

Thank you

NB. I have enabled extension = "curl.so" in my PHP.ini file

=====
UPDATE

Here is some of our code that be used:

```
$api = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=-1.597146899999999&lng=65.21213&distance=5000&count=100&access_token=$accesstoken&sig=$sig";

$response = get_curl($api);

function get_curl($url) {
    if(function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        echo curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    } else{
        return file_get_contents($url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be something to do with the endpoint you are calling? Might need to see some code to help on this one.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have edit my question with sample code we use. Basically we just want to crawl instagram activities in a location in real time.

Comment: I also have checked the same code in different server with continues running 24 hours every minute, and it runs well

Comment: Does the access log for your App show anything? Are the cron HTTP requests hitting your App? What are the response codes?

Comment: What does your cron.yaml look like?

Comment: The log in our server say "host couldn't resolve"

Comment: For cron.yaml we don't use cron in Google App Engine, we have seperated server for our cron execution that continuously call our Google App Engine url file